# sql sum for select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table Finance with following columns:
|ID|Year|Month|Value|
and my select is:

```
SELECT VALUE, YEAR, MONTH 
FROM FINANCE GROUP BY YEAR
```

and the result is:

```
3056.25, 2015, I
3445.62, 2015, II
3445.62, 2015, III
9251.22, 2015, IV
3445.62, 2015, V
8102.00, 2015, VI
8753.25, 2015, VII
3204.00, 2015, XIII
6555.25, 2015, IX
3206.00, 2015, X
3057.25, 2015, XI
2010.00, 2015, XII
1056.25, 2016, I
4000.00, 2016, II
```

What I want to do, is to get summary after each year, for example:

```
3056.25, 2015, I
3445.62, 2015, II
9251.22, 2015, IV
8102.00, 2015, VI
8753.25, 2015, VII
3204.00, 2015, XIII
6555.25, 2015, IX
3206.00, 2015, X
3057.25, 2015, XI
2010.00, 2015, XII
**57532,08, 2015,NULL**
1056.25, 2016, I
4000.00, 2016, II
**5056,25, 2016, NULL**
```

How to achive this?

Comment: *Do it in the client* is probably the best answer.  Please add tags for the specific database you are using.

Comment: I would prefer to do this in a reporting tool such as ssrs, however, if you need this to work in ssms, then you can emulate group sums with a union of 1 for detail and a union of 2 for sums and then order by your group field and the calculated union field.

Comment: The query would not run since it doesn't have month and value in group by.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `UNION ALL` to add agregated values:

```
SELECT VALUE, YEAR, MONTH 
FROM finance
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(VALUE), YEAR, NULL
FROM finance
GROUP BY YEAR
ORDER BY YEAR, CASE WHEN MONTH = 'I' THEN 1
                    WHEN MONTH = 'II' THEN 2
                     ...
                    ELSE 13
               END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use GROUP BY ROLLUP or CUBE in your use case.
Cube will give you every combination of the fields in your group by.

Try this:

```
SELECT VALUE, YEAR, MONTH 
FROM finance -- gives you the data like you have it
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(VALUE), YEAR, MONTH 
FROM FINANCE GROUP BY CUBE (YEAR, MONTH) -- appends the SUM combinations of all dimensions
```

If cube gives you "too much" try rollup...Rollup will maintain the ordering hierarchy in your group by clause

But realistically, if you want to return all the data along with the aggregate to the application , you might as well not bother with the aggregation on the DB side, because the APP code could do the summations...just a thought